# Dexie.js getting results in a proper way

Tags: dexie

My question is regarding approach of data.
Lets say i have table of 700 records of files and some data to them like date, name etc.
Example:

```
{
blob:....,
name:'Name',
date:'13-11-2020',
type:'text/html'
....
}
```

Now i want to do some sorting, filtering and pagination in spa app like vue.
Is it better to do db.files.toArray(COSTOMFILTER,PAGINATION,SORTINNG function) and return to view or get all data to array and sort them there ? list = await db.files.toArray().

Also is it possible to limit return elements ? for example I don`t want blob in my return elements.
NO Blob
{
name:'Name',
date:'13-11-2020',
type:'text/html'
....
}
Or return answer just pointing to blob in memory ? I ask because files can be large.
Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the combination of sorting and filtering and pagination, there is no silver bullet on how to approach it. Generally:

- try to squeeze out what you can by using a [compound index](https://dexie.org/docs/Compound-Index) to combine filtering of multiple fields and ordering.
- In case dataset is huge and pages are small but not possible to combine filtering and order in an index, consider using the index for sorting only and do the filtering on top of that. See some hints on [this page](https://dexie.org/docs/Collection/Collection.offset()).

Regarding your other question about selecting fields: In IndexedDB it's only possible to select whole objects ([Collection.toArray()](https://dexie.org/docs/Collection/Collection.toArray())) or just the primary keys ([Collection.primaryKeys()](https://dexie.org/docs/Collection/Collection.primaryKeys())) - not certain properties. Blobs are a bit special though: They are (or should be at least) lazy loaded anyway so they should not starve memory until you start reading from them.

Comment: Hey thx for info. For now i implemented as filter and pagination. Is there any better solution to "cache" part of results? for example now filter is trigger every time pagination change.
` filesDB = await filesDB.orderBy(sortOptions).filter((file) => {    return _filterElements(file, filters);  });  if (isRev !== undefined) {    filesDB.reverse();  }  const count = await filesDB.count();  filesDB = await filesDB.offset(offset).limit(pagination.pageSize).toArray(); return { count: count, filesDB: filesDB };`

Comment: There's no caching in Dexie so you would need to implement that yourself